# Kind find the limit of the following question

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the limit of the following?
lim(h->0) ((2+h)^0.5 -(2)^0.5)/h

Note:
I'm struggling to make the denominator positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First way:**

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{2+h}-\sqrt2}h=(\sqrt x)'|_{x=2}=\frac1{2\sqrt2}$$

**Second way:**

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{2+h}-\sqrt2}h=\frac{2+h-2}{h(\sqrt{2+h}+\sqrt2)}=\frac1{\sqrt{2+h}+\sqrt2}\xrightarrow[h\to 0]{}\frac1{2\sqrt2}$$

Comment: Ah, thank you. I've been doing it the second way, but was overseeing the obvious... Thank you again. :)

Comment: I know :) I was just waiting for the time limit to come to an end.

Comment: Oh, Ok...:)....

Comment: Here is another question for you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569230/cant-find-the-limit-of-the-following :P