# Can't find the limit of the following

Tags: calculus, limits

I can't find the limit of the the following:

$$\lim_{p\to1} \frac{ p^{1/3} - 1 }{p - 1}$$

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting $p^{\frac13}=q\implies p=q^3$ as $p\to1, q\to1$

$$\lim_{p\to1}\frac{p^{\frac13}-1}{p-1}$$

$$=\lim_{q\to1}\frac{q-1}{q^3-1}$$

$$=\lim_{q\to1}\frac{(q-1)}{(q-1)(q^2+q+1)}$$

$$=\lim_{q\to1}\frac1{q^2+q+1}\text{ as }q-1\ne0\iff q\ne1\text{ as } q\to1$$

$$=\cdots$$

Comment: So the answer is 1/3. Thank you. :) I'll mark as correct as soon as the time limit is over.

Comment: @LukeTaylor, my pleasure. How will you handle $$\lim_{p\to1}\frac{p^{\frac mn}-1}{p-1}?$$

Comment: I would set a variable to p^(m/n). And therefor the variable^(n/m) would be equal to p. Then I would substitute that variable into the question to solve the limit.

Comment: @LukeTaylor, $p^{\frac mn}=q\implies p=q^{\frac nm}$. Try setting $p^{\frac 1n}=q$

Comment: Then p would be q^n

Answer (score 2):

Besides the nice answer you already got, what about l'Hospital?:

$$\lim_{p\to 1}\frac{p^{1/3}-1}{p-1}=\lim_{p\to 1}\;\frac13p^{-2/3}=\frac13$$

Comment: Thank you. Looks complicated though. :P

Comment: It really isn't and, in fact, l'Hospital is one of the strongest methods to calculate some particular kinds of limits...so much that some limits seem to be almost impossible to evaluate otherwise.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I'll check out l'Hospital for future reference. :)

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule is powerful, but it's usually pedagogically wrong at the level of this question. Understanding why L'Hôpital works requires you to be familiar with derivatives, differentiability, the sandwich theorem and Cauchy's mean value theorem just to get started. In an elementry calculus test, be forewarned, I know professors that will mark an answer using L'Hôpital as wrong, unless the student also provides definitions and proofs for all of the above if they haven't been presented in class yet.

Comment: Any instructor, teacher and/or proffesor I know, up and including me, will downmark *any* question that isn't well explained and justified, and this of course includes stuff that wasn't covered in the course. We're assuming here that l'H was already taught, otherwise it doesn't fit.

Comment: However in this question it is intrinsically not possible to use L'Hospital because of circular reasoning. The given limit is actually the derivative of $f(x) = x^{1/3}$ at point $1$ and and L'Hospital assumes the use of differentiation. The limit therefore has to be justified by the use of algebraic manipulations.

Comment: Well, that's one possibility, yet I could simply know derivatives and l'H, and I could also know that $$f'(1):=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(1+h)^{1/3} -1}h$$which, of course, is equivalent *but not the same* as the given limit. I can't see the circularity here **if** derivatives and l'H are already known.

Comment: To DonAntoio: The derivative can't be known unless you calculate this limit by some other means. Derivatives are not magical formulas but they are result of limit operations (which are evaluated by techniques other than differentiation). That's why I see them them as circular. In this case if you L'Hospital then you have to use the fact that $(x^{1/3})' = (1/3)x^{-2/3}$ and this means you already know that $\lim_{x \to a}(x^{1/3} - a^{1/3})/(x - a) = (1/3)a^{-2/3}$ and then you can directly put $ a = 1$ to get answer.

Comment: In my opinion L'Hospital can't be used to evaluate a limit of the form $\lim_{x \to a}(f(x) - f(a))/(x - a)$.

Comment: There are lots of methods to calculate derivatives **after** one knows the definition by means of limits, @ParamanandSingh...fortunately enough. One of them is by means of the derivative of the inverse function. So I could know the very easy (by definition or whatever) $$(x^3)'=3x^2\implies y=x^{1/3}\implies x=y^3\implies y'=\frac1{(y^{-1})'}=\frac1{3x^2}=\frac1{3y^{3/2}}\ldots$$ and thus I could know the derivative **not** by means of the definition...

Comment: Imo l'H can be used to evaluate a limit of the kind you wrote in your last comment @ParamanandSingh *as long* as the derivatives and the method are **already** known. I agree that with basic stuff that can be weird from an educative point of view, yet when one reaches l'H and stuff one has already studied the basics enough to understand what's going on.

Comment: Still I would prefer that L'Hospital and its even more powerful cousin Taylor series should be used for things which are really tough and not for the particular simple problem here. A problem suitable for use of L'Hospital is at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569043/a-limit-problem-related-to-log-sec-x Unfortunately I am yet to solve this one.

Comment: As for making some mental muscle I agree with you in that, @ParamanandSingh: leave stronger weapons for stronger problems.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11536/discussion-between-paramanand-singh-and-donantonio)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Let 
$$f(p)=p^{1/3}$$
Can you see why your limit is $f'(1)$?